# Why I am getting error while using Pattern class to identify string whether its valid or not?

Tags: java, regex

```
package app;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class ValidIdentifierDemo 
{
    public static void main(String s[])
    {
        Pattern p=new Pattern.compile("[a-z A-z][a-z A-Z 0-9]+"); // error here
        Matcher m=p.matcher("int"); //2 or s[0] in place of int?

        if (m.find() && m.group().equals(s[0])) // 3 why s[0] shouldn't i use "int"
        {
            System.out.println("Valid");

        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("InValid");

        }
    }
}
```

Why should I use `s[0]` in //2 //3

Output Shown

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
    at app.ValidIdentifierDemo.main(ValidIdentifierDemo.java:11)
```

Comment: By the way `[a-z A-z]` allows space in the text.

Answer (score 2):

You have to do:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[a-z A-z][a-z A-Z 0-9]+");
```

i.e. remove the `new` keyword, as the `.compile()` method will *produce* a `Pattern` for you.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `new` keyword.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[a-z A-z][a-z A-Z 0-9]+");
```

`Pattern`'s constructor is not accessible and a new `Pattern` is initialized by static invocation of `Pattern.compile(String pattern)`.

Also invoking a constructor requires parenthesis after the constructor name, and a list of arguments in between the parenthesis if applicable.